# Can you remove bit locker encryption by resetting laptop

Tags: windows-10, lenovo-laptop, bitlocker

I was given a used Lenovo laptop the other day. I reset the whole computer and erased all data. This went fine, I logged into my Microsoft account and set up my whole computer. After a while the computer asked me to update, I did this but on boot up it went into bit-locker recovery. I have checked my Microsoft account and there is no key. I did not set up bitlocker encryption. I asked the previous owner if they set up bitlocker encryption but they hadn't, and it isn't in their Microsoft account.

I understand that I can't get in without the recovery key but is there anyway I can just factory reset the laptop? If I do this will the bitlocker encryption be removed?

Comment: Bitlocker is not enforced by your computer. You can simply reinstall Windows and recreate the system partition in the installation process.